# Hibernate insert into oracle DB , unexpected token: VALUES

Tags: hibernate, oracle10g

I am trying to do create a insert query into my Oracle 10g DB. It keeps giving me this error:

**ERROR PARSER:33 - line 1:115: unexpected token: VALUES**

this is my DAO method to insert

```
public void uploadFile(String createUser, Integer id, byte[] file, String name, String size, String mime) {

    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try {
       Query up = session.createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO FILES(CREATE_DATE, CREATE_USER, FILE_DATA, FILE_ID, FILE_MIME, FILE_NAME, FILE_SIZE, ID) VALUES(SYSDATE, :createUser, :file, FILE_ID_SEQ.nextval, :mime, :name, :size, :id) ");

        up.setInteger("id", id);
        up.setBinary("file", file);
        up.setString("name", name);
        up.setString("size", size);
        up.setString("mime", mime);
        up.setString("createUser", createUser);

        up.executeUpdate();

    } catch(HibernateException e) {
        throw new HibernateException(e);
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the full stacktrace?

Comment: just tried to print the stacktrace and that is the only thing I get is that error

Comment: As far as I understand, without a stacktrace you can't even be sure that error happens in the shown code and not somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Only the INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... form is supported; not the INSERT INTO ... VALUES ... form.

Core reference, chapter 13.

Ups, sorry, It is plain sql, I say nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Check the column lists, you missed the size:

```
FILES(CREATE_DATE, CREATE_USER, FILE_DATA, FILE_ID,             FILE_MIME, FILE_NAME, ID) 
VALUES(SYSDATE,    :createUser, :file,     FILE_ID_SEQ.nextval, :mime,     :name,     :size, :id)
```

Comment: sorry that is not the problem it was a typo on my part when writing up the question. @Stefan Steinegger

Comment: Can you turn on Hibernate "show_sql" parameter and print the SQL before being sent to the server?  Or print the SQL from the Oracle logs?  Perhaps there is just a simple syntax problem from the generated statement.